# udev 99-hide-disks.rules is no longer working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev

A while ago I created a `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-hide-disks.rules` file on Ubuntu which worked fine. At some point, the hidden disks started reappearing in Dolphin and other file managers.

The file hasn't changed, it still contains the following

```
KERNEL=="sda1", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
KERNEL=="sda2", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
KERNEL=="sda3", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
KERNEL=="sda4", ENV{UDISKS_PRESENTATION_HIDE}="1"
```

but sda1 and sda4 (only) are no longer hidden. How can this be?

I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

udisks v2 has removed the "hide" option (although "ignore" may be *sort of* similar), and renamed the others. According to the `udisks(8)` manual page:

```
DEVICE INFORMATION
       udisks relies on recent versions of udev(7) and the Linux kernel.
       Influential device properties in the udev database include:

       UDISKS_SYSTEM
           If set, this overrides the value of the HintSystem property.

       UDISKS_IGNORE
           If set, this overrides the value of the HintIgnore property.

       UDISKS_AUTO
           If set, this overrides the value of the HintAuto property.

       UDISKS_CAN_POWER_OFF
           If set, this overrides the value of the CanPowerOff property.

       UDISKS_NAME
           The name to use for the device when presenting it in an user
           interface. This corresponds to the HintName property.

       UDISKS_ICON_NAME
           The icon to use for the device when presenting it in an user
           interface. If set, the name must adhere to the freedesktop.org icon
           theme specification[5]. This corresponds to the HintIconName
           property.

       UDISKS_SYMBOLIC_ICON_NAME
           The icon to use for the device when presenting it in an user
           interface using a symbolic icon. If set, the name must adhere to
           the freedesktop.org icon theme specification[5]. This corresponds
           to the HintSymbolicIconName property.

       UDISKS_FILESYSTEM_SHARED
           If set to 1, the filesystem on the device will be mounted in a
           shared directory (e.g.  /media/VolumeName) instead of a private
           directory (e.g.  /run/media/$USER/VolumeName) when the
           Filesystem.Mount() method is handled.
```

Comment: Okay so changing the name worked. Apart from making life more difficult, what's the difference?

Comment: Just to name it in simple terms, `UDISKS_IGNORE` is the right option.